# Magento 1.9 adding attributes costs just once

Tags: magento-1.9

I want to add an attribute to a product which is not directly linked to the ammount of products you buy. For example: when you buy ten t-shirts for 1 dollar and choose for the attribute 'with print' (which costs an extra 20 dollars) I want to add the attribute price **just once** and not ten times. So the total has to be **10 (shirts) x 1 + 20 (extra price for printing) = 30** and not 10 (shirts) x 1 + 10 x 20(extra price for printing) = 210

Can anybody tell me how to configure this? Are attributes the way to go or do I have to configure another kind of product.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

you want to configuable product view page,and add cart to one product's "print" price?

It is not configuable product rule, configuable product is just configuable.

so, how about create just simple product (printing t-shirt product) and alert message in cart page when counting configuable product has attribute 'with-print' (observer used).

if you want to product's one page view, just use bundle product, but it is not good solution.